# Python C API use WinPython Python interpreter instead of standard python interpreter

Tags: python, c++, python-embedding

When embedding Python into my C/C++ application, how do I correctly use the WinPython's python interpreter that is found in the root directory "WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.1" as opposed to the python interpreter that is found one level down in "WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.1/python-3.4.4.amd64"?

When I try using the python interpreter that is found in "WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.1/python-3.4.4.amd64" I am unable to successfully run my module. However when I run the module with the python interpreter found in the root directory, I am able to run my module correctly.

I tried renaming the "WinPython Interpreter" to "python" and then setting the python home:

```
wchar_t PythonHome[1024];
std::wcsncpy(PythonHome, L"C:\\Users\\jchen114\\Lasagne\\WinPython\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.1", 1024);
Py_SetPythonHome(PythonHome);
Py_Initialize();
```

The error that I get when running the module with the standard python interpreter is about a

```
"C:\dev\MinGW\bin\g++.exe" -shared -g ... sorry, an unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in 
#include <Python.h>
^
```

Does that mean I just need a 64-bit g++ compiler?

Please advise.

Comment: There is no language C/C++. Only the **different** languages C and C++! As you asked about the C API, I removed the wrong tag. If you use C++, feel free to change the tag to C++.

Comment: Right. But this question applies to both.

Comment: On second reading, you apparently use a C++ compiler, so no, it does not! But I correct the tag to C++.

Answer (score 0):

So to solve, there is a g++ compiler that WinPython ships with that it uses. Its in the Scripts folder. If you put that in your path that should do the trick.